# Finding the one nearest hopsital to my location even if it's 1000,000 KM far

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to write an android program that uses Google API to find the nearest hospital to the phone location. Note that the hospital is not necessarily in my neighborhood or city. It could be very far but it is the nearest one.

By searching, I was referred to a code that looks only within a specific Radius around the phone, and finds all the hospitals nearby. The code is below:

```
private String makeUrl(double latitude, double longitude,String place) {
     StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?");

    if (place.equals("")) {
            urlString.append("&location=");
            urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
            urlString.append(",");
            urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
            urlString.append("&radius=1000");
         //   urlString.append("&types="+place);
            urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
    } else {
            urlString.append("&location=");
            urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
            urlString.append(",");
            urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
            urlString.append("&radius=1000");
            urlString.append("&types="+place);
            urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
    }


    return urlString.toString();
}
```

This code worked okay with me. How can I modify it to achieve my goal? Thank you?

Comment: Increase the radius to 100000 and and you get a response according to the distance. Then place select the lowest distance place as your required place.

Comment: Is the received list ordered from nearest to furthest? So I can pick only the first one?

Comment: yes. Your requirement is to show the nearest one hospital right. So just select the one.

Comment: Are you sure you understand my question in the comment? I am saying is the list returned by Google API sorted from nearest to furthest?

Comment: yes Google api returned sorted from nearest to furthest result

Comment: alright, thanks. You can post it as an answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43251/discussion-between-renjith-krishnan-and-traveling-salesman)

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
private String makeUrl(double latitude, double longitude,String place) {
StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?");

if (place.equals("")) {
        urlString.append("&location=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
        urlString.append("&radius=50000");  // <<-- change here
     //   urlString.append("&types="+place);
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
} else {
        urlString.append("&location=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
        urlString.append("&radius=50000");  // <<-- change here
        urlString.append("&types="+place);
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
}
return urlString.toString();
}
```

Comment: So your idea is to just increase the radius?

Comment: i also build some map app using google maps V2 in my project and if i change the radius to less than 15.000, it will showing nearby places on my island, if i change bigger than 15.000, it will show another nearby places in another island.

Answer (score 2):

Increase the radius to 100000 and and you get a response according to the distance. Then place select the lowest distance place as your required place.

Comment: I will try it and give you a check if it worked out.

Comment: No, I didn't work as you said. The first hospital in the list is not the closest hospital to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

apply shortest path algorithm by dijkstra . which you have to use graph structure first to use paths on the GPS system to hospitals. then you can apply shortest path algorithm .